# OpenGL Image warping using lookup table

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on an Android application that slims or fatten faces by detecting face. Currently, I have achieved that by using Thin-plate spline algorithm. http://ipwithopencv.blogspot.com.tr/2010/01/thin-plate-spline-example.html

The problem is that the algorithm is not fast enough for me so I decided to change it to OpenGL. After some research, I see that the lookup table texture is the best option for this. I have a set of control points for source image and new positions of them for warp effect. How should I create lookup table texture to get warp effect?